# Weird graphics problem when playing games

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I have installed Need For Speed Most Wanted-2005 on my laptop. But, when I tried to play the game, some wired graphical problem occurred. I have attached some screenshots regarding the problem.

I have also tried Assassins creed 1 and some other games. For all of these, I am facing same problem. But, in case of FIFA series (Fifa 9,10,11), there is no problem.

My laptop specifications:

- HP pavilion g6 64 bit
- Windows 7 ultimate - 64bit
- intel core i3 processor
- 4GB of RAM
- 1GB of AMD radeon Graphics

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are your video drivers up-to-date?

Comment: yes, they are..

Comment: This sounds like your graphics card is overheating.  If you're running an i3, your laptop is probably pretty old, so it could be that the laptop is dying.

Comment: But, some games (like FIFA 14) with better graphics is running without any problem.

Comment: Those games probably don't use the GPU as much as the other games do.  Or use the features that are causing the artifacting.

Comment: Yeah it's a dying card. Or a dying laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This is either a driver issue or some hardware problem. Have you checked the fans for dirt or dust? This might also be some temperature issue in general. Have you tried verifying hardware temperatures (especially GPU)?

Comment: I have recently cleaned my laptop fans to make it free from dust. So, fans aren't the problem, I think. and GPU temperature is 50 degree C in normal use. and when the game is running , it becoming maximum 60 - not more that that.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati most likely some hardware problem then (like memory corruption). Unfortunately hard or impossible to diagnose online (and even in person).

Answer (score 0):

Given that your laptop runs FIFA 14 without any problems, it appears that the game files themselves may have been corrupted or improperly installed.

You can try to reinstall the game to see if that fixes the problem. If not, then it's either a hardware problem or a problem with the game disc. It's difficult to determine which is the culprit at this point.

NFS Most Wanted, for a game coming from 2005, doesn't actually cause a lot of compatibility issues with modern hardware, so this kind of problem is somewhat unexpected from it.

Answer (score -1):

I can only tell that you should contact the organisation from where you purchased the system. you could do two things

- format your computer with stock os.
  Install video drivers and install directx latest version.
- if above methods don't resolve the issue then contact the organisation you purchased the computer from. (If it is not a software problem then obviously it is a hardware problem). Probably you could get replacement.

Comment: Ew, no.  A graphics problem like this isn't going to be resolved by reformatting the computer.

Comment: What could be wrong. Is the problem same with all games ?

Comment: @Fennekin, Not for all games. Till now, for NFS-MW and AssassinCreeds1. Fifa is running normally

Comment: It must be an issue with game graphics method (old method with shaders up to 2.0) on the laptop

Comment: Just install catalyst 13 beta